# How to load sprite from another class and change it on input XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am just learning XNA and i have some basic questions.

1. Let's say I have class Car and want to load/draw sprites. How should I do it? Xna created methods for that but they are in Game class.
2. After I deal with loading my sprite using custom class my class to have 3 states and depending on state. I want it to draw different sprite. I would like to have them all loaded in array of Texture2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, these methods are in the `Game` class and unless you change radically how things work, you'll have to get used to that fact.

However, as soon as you inherit from `DrawableGameComponent` (which all your game objects should do if you want them to draw/update), you'll see that all your objects need to have that `Game` class passed to them in the constructor anyway because of their base class. You can then use it from there to load your textures :

```
public class Car : DrawableGameComponent
{
    private Texture2D texture;

    public Car(Game game) : base(game)
    {
        texture = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("mytexture");
    }
}
```

Or hold a reference to it and load them later. This also means somewhere in your `Game1.cs` you have something like

```
Car car = new Car(this);
```

or, if you're loading it from an other file, that file need to know your Game class in order to create your car.

To draw the sprites, simply use the

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
```

method of `DrawableGameComponent`.

---

If you want to make it less painful, you could still create a static class that holds your Game class (and possibly your `SpriteBatch`, as it will be quite useful) :

```
public static class GameHolder
{
    public static Game Game { get; set; }
}
```

So your game components can be created like this :

```
public class Car : DrawableGameComponent
{
    private Texture2D texture;

    public Car() : base(GameHolder.Game)
    {
        texture = GameHolder.Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("mytexture");
    }
}
```

And don't forget to feed the Game value from your Game1 class :

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        GameHolder.Game = this;
    }
}
```

---

To handle states, you can indeed load them all in an array and print one of them. To remove the logic from the `Draw` method, you can also use an other `Texture2D` that will hold the current sprite you want to render.

```
public class Car : DrawableGameComponent
{
    private List<Texture2D> states;
    private Texture2D currentState;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Car(Game game, SpriteBatch sb) : base(GameHolder.Game)
    {
        states.Add(game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("state1"));
        states.Add(game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("state2"));
        states.Add(game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("state3"));
        currentState = states[0];
        spriteBatch = sb;
    }
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (someCondition)
        {
            currentState = states[0];
        }
        else if (someOtherCondition)
        {
            currentState = states[1];
        }
        else if (moreConditions)
        {
            currentState = states[2];
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(currentState, new Vector2(0,0), Color.White);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Draw method don't really care you have multiple states to handle.

---

If you need a detailed tutorial, the [Platformer Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) is really awesome.